# Strongloop: Not validating foreign key when creating a HasAndBelongsToMany relation via REST API

Tags: model, loopbackjs, has-and-belongs-to-many, strongloop

In my loopback/strongloop project I have the two models 'apis' and 'clients' which have a HasAndBelongsToMany relation, i.e. each api can have multiple clients and each client can belong to multiple apis. 
Let's assume the following scenario where I create one instance of each model and want to link them together (via REST API):

1) POST /apis    => create new api instance

2) POST /clients => create new clients instance and link it to existing api instance

3) PUT /apis/{apiId}/clients/rel/{clientId} => link an existing api to an existing client instance

The existence of an api with '*apiId*' is checked, but the existence of  client with '*clientId*' not, this means I can create such relation with an invalid or not existing client. Is this a bug in strongloop/loopback or what am I missing?